WCF Async call leads to dead-lock?
I have a WCF contract with one synchronous method and one asynchronous method defined and implemented as:
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFooService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string GetFoo(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> GetBarAsync();
}

public class FooService : IFooService
{
    public string GetFoo(int value)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public Task<string> GetBarAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(6000).Wait();
            return "done!";
        });
    }
}

On the client side, I have a console program:
class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding();
        var proxy = new ChannelFactory<IFooService>(binding, new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/Test")).CreateChannel();


        Console.WriteLine("GetFoo result: " + proxy.GetFoo(1));
        var tmp = await proxy.GetBarAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("GetBarAsync result: " + tmp);
        Console.WriteLine("GetFoo result: " + proxy.GetFoo(2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

It output GetFoo result: 1, waited 6 seconds and then output GetBarAsync result: done!,  so far everything is expected.  However, it just hangs there and never outputs the last line which is GetFoo result: 2.
Can someone please help explain why?  Is it a dead-lock?  Or WCF Channel doesn't support async calls?

Not relevant to the problem, but instead of Task.Delay(6000).Wait(); I would suggest as an improvement for the question Thread.Sleep(6000);, which is simpler and does (almost) the same thing.

The WCF model for async calls is not based of Task, but rather on events, see documentation. See also here for an approach to enable use of await on the client side.

Try don't block on async code and see whether the problem still occurs. .Wait() blocks the running thread and that's not recommended in async code. There are 2 ways to achieve this: 1. start an async lambda inside of Task.Run maybe async () => await Task.Delay(1000). or remove all that Task.Run stuff and implement GetBarAsync asynchonously.

@KlausGütter you're looking at very old docs. WCF always used the APM model ie Begin/EndMethod. Since .NET Framework 4.something svcutil generates Task-based methods by default. The docs you link to only refer to switching from APM to the event-based model for desktop applications

@KlausGütter the current version of the tool says /async                             - Generate both synchronous and begin/end asynchronous method signatures. Default:                                       generate synchronous and task-based asynchronous method signatures. (Short Form:                                       /a)

@Jake what's the actual service code? How is concurrency configured? WCF has its own concurrency model. A service can be a singleton with method calls synchronized by WCF itself, there may be a different service instance per session, or there may be a different instance per call.

@Jake the async client methods have nothing to do with the service implementation. The proxy generated by svcutil has GetFoo, GetFooAsync, GetBar and GetBarAsync methods. The async methods don't block the client while waiting for the service to answer and hove nothing to do with the operation implementation

@Jake I suspect the real problem here is that you tried to reuse the service interface instead of generating a proxy client with svcutil. Check Calling a synchronous WCF method asynchronously using ChannelFactory.

I think it's possible for your last question, because I saw the following error on the test client.

In the end, I changed the client code without changing the service code. It's working well at the moment.
 Console.WriteLine("GetFoo result: " + proxy.GetFoo(1));
 var tmp =proxy.GetBar();
 Console.WriteLine("GetBarAsync result: " + tmp);
 Console.WriteLine("GetFoo result: " + proxy.GetFoo(2));
 var tmp1 = proxy.GetBar();
 Console.WriteLine("GetBarAsync result: " + tmp1);
 Console.ReadLine();



This doesn't answer the question, it changes the calls. There's nothing wrong with Task-based proxy methods. The WCF Test Client predates async/await so it can't call the generated async methods. That doesn't mean they can't be called

So after numerous trying, I found the culprit is the channel.  Seems WCF channel is a one time use for async calls.  If I create a new channel, the second sync call returns as expected.
Console.WriteLine("GetFoo result: " + proxy.GetFoo(1));
var tmp = await proxy.GetBarAsync();
Console.WriteLine("GetBarAsync result: " + tmp);

****** recreate channel solve the problem ******
proxy = new ChannelFactory<IFooService>(binding, new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/Test")).CreateChannel();
************************************************

Console.WriteLine("GetFoo result: " + proxy.GetFoo(2));
Console.ReadLine();

